# Cannot run qgis_process on WSL2, its trying to connect to a display

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, qt, windows-10, command-line

I'm trying to run qgis_process on WSL2 on Windows 10 using Ubuntu and I get this Error message:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display xxx.xxx.xxx.x:x
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was 
found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. 
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, 
xcb.

Aborted
```

The same thing happens when I run QGIS from the command line, but with qgis_process loading a GUI doesnt make sense, because I want it to run in the command line only. Im using QGIS 3.24.1. I already uninstalled my old QGIS version and installed the new one, and it didnt help.

I'm not so familiar with Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unfortunately not entirely clear from your question how you are calling `qgis_process`, but I'm attempting to answer anyways because I did run into the exact error before.

If you want to call the `qgis_process` which comes with your windows installation of QGIS you should run `qgis_process` from within the OSGeo4W shell.
Running via WSL2 will work with following command (but then again I don't know why you would be using WSL for this, you could just aswell run the command in `cmd`)

```
cmd.exe /c OSGeo4W.bat qgis_process-qgis list
```

Note the *-qgis* suffix in the command.

However, from your error message and because you are using WSL I assume that you might be running one of the QGIS docker images inside WSL2. That's atleast where I stumbled across the error by running something like the below command, which results in exactly the error you mentioned.

```
$ docker exec -it qgis_test sh -c "qgis_process list"
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted
```

To solve this you need to tell QGIS to run in a *headless* context (meaning without graphical display).

This can be achieved by setting the the `QT_QPA_PLATFORM` environment variable:

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM="offscreen" && qgis_process list
```

Or another option would be to use a virtual framebuffer as display output:

```
export DISPLAY=:99 && qgis_process list
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped:
    "export QT_QPA_PLATFORM="offscreen" && qgis_process list".
Im running qgis_process within the WLS2 terminal, so I can use other linux tools and applications, while coding within windows. For qgis im not using docker, but installed it normally.